# CAD software for OpenSolaris?

Tags: opensolaris, cad

I would like to install CAD software again on my laptop.  I used to use Rhinoceros 3d and AutoCAD for most stuff, but that was on the Windows side of things.

What can I do for the Solaris side?

Walter

Comment: Not to rain on your idea, but for CAD (however much people try to prove opposite) windows platform is an industry standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I will end up installing winders through virtualbox.  All of these open source CAD software packages are too primitive and wouldn't allow me to do any detailed engineering with them.  I am just doing a hobby type of project, but it still has tolerances for parts to function.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [BRLCad](http://brlcad.org/)? It is listed for Solaris, not sure about OpenSolaris.

EDIT: [This thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/ug-bosug@mail.opensolaris.org/msg00596.html) seems to indicate there is support available for unlisted platforms.

Comment: It is primitive, but I guess I can't be both a beggar and chooser.